# Windows Service to back up Excel File into Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services

I have to backup excel file  daily and i need that my excel file could automatically upload on SQL server at exact time which i want.
I am new to C# so dont know from where i can get proper help regarding this issue.I have searched in google but confused by many methods and complicated codes etc. 
I am much desperate now so please help me out and send me links about this.

Comment: Upload to what? As a binary in a specific table inside the database or just to a file on the database server's file system for import or...? You'll need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the windows service in C#.net to achieve this.
Details of Windows Service with sample:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample